# SQL query to identify pairs with duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to write a query which will pair up impressions and conversions from the same IP address in my database. I have a table of impressions and their IP addresses, and an impression can be of the type 'view' or 'conversion' (defined in the column 'name').

So basically, I need to identify groups of records with the same IP address, which contain both a view and a conversion.

After an hour of Googling I've got as far as the below, which isn't very far but should give an idea of the objects involved:

```
SELECT ip_address, name, COUNT(1) as CNT 
FROM Impressions
GROUP BY ip_address, name;
```

Can anyone advise on the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `HAVING` clause with a conditional count. You also need to remove `name` from the `GROUP BY` as this will treat your two different types separately.

```
SELECT  ip_address, 
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'View' THEN 1 END) AS Views,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'Conversion' THEN 1 END) AS Conversions,
        COUNT(1) as CNT 
FROM    Impressions
GROUP BY ip_address
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'View' THEN 1 END) > 0
AND     COUNT(CASE WHEN Name = 'Conversion' THEN 1 END) > 0;
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you. Just for my own understanding, am I right in thinking that the first three COUNT statements provide the output table, but it's the final two which do the actual grouping?

Comment: None of the count statements do any grouping, the first 3 as you have said provide the columns for the output table, the second two in the having clause just limit the results to ip addresses with at least 1 view and at least 1 conversion. It is very much like a where clause but it is used with aggregates.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT 
  i.ip_address AS ip, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CAST(i.name AS CHAR)) AS nameList,
  SUM(IF(i.name = 'View', 1, 0)) AS viewCount, 
  SUM(IF(i.name = 'Conversion', 1, 0)) AS conversionCount
FROM Impressions i
GROUP BY i.ip_address;
```

You will get a comma delimited list of names containing both 'view' & 'conversion' and their separate counts.

Comment: Should your expressions for `viewCount` and `converstionCount` be sums?

Comment: I have modified my query now you can get sum of all views and conversions for a particular ip as `viewCount` and `conversionCount`.

Answer (score -1):

Please try...

SELECT ip_address, name, COUNT(1) cnt as CNT FROM Impressions 
GROUP BY  name,IP_address
Having count(IP_address) > 1;

Comment: This doesn't identify when it contains both a view AND a conversion.